# File Icon in 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, filesystem

I just updated from 14.04 to 16.04. Now when I open the filesystem in the sidebar, it creates a new file icon for each instance. It doesn't do this with any other programs (e.g. the Firefox icon is used to both open a new instance and to work with the open one). Is there an easy way to fix this?